# FLUTTER: Package install error: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE] on SAMSUNG

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, installation

I have setup environment for Flutter using Android Studio and after fixing so many unthinkable issues, I could finally run first sample application on emulator. But this won't run on my phone. An error for INSUFFICIENT STORAGE appears like this;

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM C7010 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
Package install error: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]
Error launching application on SM C7010.
```

Above is output from Android Studio. I have also tried same through command prompt, but the error persist. Following are screenshots from CMD and I am also attaching screenshot of my phone storage; which I think is enough for installation of apps;

[image]

[image]
[image]

***And contrary to the situation***, it does not give storage error for Native apps I have been developing. To check this again, I have started new native (Java) project in Android Studio and tried to install the app. It just worked fine, and the new app got installed straight away. Following are the screenshots;

[image]

[image]

Can someone guide me about the fix.? I have tried a lot of solutions being posted but none of those fix it; as apparently storage is not an issue. Because if storage is an issue; how does a Native app get installed on the same time!

**UPDATE: Feb 19, 2021**

I cleared more space, and error persisted even when 8-GB free space was available. Then I sacrificed my WhatsApp data, and now I got 21-GB free space on phone. And the error still persist, I have also cleared cache of all big-sized apps on phone and also restarted. Also, it won't let me install as APK file directly from storage with the same error;

[image]
[image]
[image]

I just do not get this!

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem, but on the emulator.

I solved it going to `Android Studio` -> `AVD Manager` -> Click edit button to go to the `Settings` of your emulator -> increase `Internal storage`

I set it up to > 3000 Mb.

[image]

Comment: Question is not about emulator, it is about Samsung Device.

Comment: True Rizwan, I answered that because someone can have the error `FLUTTER: Package install error: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]` on the emulator, as me.

Comment: Thanks. I have the same problem with the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you dont have enough space to install app on your device try to uninstall unused app and try to run again it will work as fluter app need more space to install

Comment: Native app was running even when free space was less than 1GB. Now I have 4GB free space available. I wonder how is 4GB free space insufficient.

Comment: Now I have created more free space, and it is more than 08-GB free space on phone. Still flutter app won't install. And also, apk file is not being installed from internal storage due to same error; i.e. Insufficient Storage.

Comment: I have updated my question, because now I created more than 21-GB free space, and the error persist.